# Data modeling, double foreign key problem

Tags: database-design

I have a certain problem, while creating logical/relational model of database. I get duplicate foreign key in a table. This table is referencing 2 other tables, thorugh identyfing relationship, which reference this particular key and they have to be primary keys because they are cross-reference tables.
Something like this:

[image]

How can i fix this so i don't have duplicate keys on PARAM_VAL: id_quali1 and id_quali?

Comment: Can you please add more details to your database schema? For example, I don't see `id_quali1` used anywhere and therefor don't understand how it can be duplicated. More descriptive names of your tables and columns would also help paint a picture.

Comment: id_quali1 is just a name to point out that it is dupliacate (of id_quali but from different table), because identyfing relationships take it from the parent table. After some thought i think it can't be done differently so ill just leave 2 of them id_quali_quali_participation and id_quali_param_weight and ill check if both of them are equal when insterting.

Answer (score 1):

Like @J.D. mentions in his comment it is not obvious what problem you are trying to solve. If I were to guess PARAM_VAL could be consructed as:

```
CREATE TABLE param_val
( id_quali ... NOT NULL
, id_param ... NOT NULL
, id_cand ... NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (id_quali, id_param, id_cand) -- I guess
, FOREIGN KEY (id_quali, id_param) 
      REFERENCES param_weight(id_quali, id_param)
, FOREIGN KEY (id_quali, id_cand) 
      REFERENCES quali_participation(id_quali, id_cand)
);
```

Comment: the thing is Oracle data modeler doesn't let me delete id_quali1 (the name is just a duplicate id_quali, it does not exist in database)

Comment: @BartoszLeszczyński What error do you encounter if you try to remove it?

Comment: i cannot delete it from gui when i operate on relational model in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler, when i click on delete column it doesn't change anything

Comment: What if you create my table above but name it param_val_test and reverse engineer it into the modeller?

Comment: i just found an option to overlap attributes when engineering from logical model. It seems it can't be done from relational model which is weird

Comment: @BartoszLeszczyński Time to find another tool.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I've been struggling with the same problem myself and have just solved it, so thought I'd share.

- In the Relational Model, double click the foreign key that joins     PARAM_VAL to QUALI_PARTICIPATION. The Foreign Key Properties dialog will open.
- Under "General" you will see the offending column id_quali1, which    references id_quali from the QUALI_PARTICIPATION table.
- Click on id_quali1. A select list of columns in the PARAM_VAL table will open.
- Select id_quali and cick OK.
- In response to 'Do you want to delete generated FK columns    "id_quali1"?', click Yes.

The duplicate column will be gone.

Unfortunately you'll have to repeat the process if you ever re-engineer the Relational Model from the Logical Model.